# Facebook Canvas with Unity Integration change unity config params

Tags: html, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-canvas

Hello i'm working on a facebook game using unity3D, in the past i could just add the html code with custom configuration into the facebook canvas, but now in the new sdk and integration with unity facebook directly loads the unity3d file, ignoring all my custom html code and custom configuration.

In the documentation says that i can add custom html code in unity by using the external calls, but that means that the html header and modifications will only appear after the game is loaded and runing, is there a way to have the html header while the game is loading.

and, how i can modify the default logoimage, progressbarimage, etc.

Here is the uinty configuration and the code i have on my html document that i want to apply on my facebook game.

```
var config = {
            width: 1024, 
            height: 768,
            backgroundcolor: "FFFFFF",
            bordercolor: "383838",
            textcolor: "FFFFFF",
            logoimage: "Resources/loading.png",
            progressbarimage: "Resources/Loading-Bar_Full.png",
            progressframeimage: "Resources/Loading-Bar_Empty.png",
            disableContextMenu: true,
            params: { enableDebugging:"0" }

        };
        var u = new UnityObject2( { params: config } );
```

Html header WIP

```
<div id="header">
        <span>-Beta Build- | </span> My Game <br/>
        <img alt="Header!" src="Resources/WebHeader.png"/>
        <div id="like">
            <img alt="Like Us" src="Resources/WebLike.png"/>
        </div>
        <div id="store">
            <img alt="Earn Credits" src="Resources/WebCredits.png"/>
        </div>
        <div id="gift">
            <img alt="Send Gift" src="Resources/WebSendGift.png"/>
        </div>
        <div id="help">
            <img alt="Help" src="Resources/WebHelp.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The config params are currently not editable.  It's one of those feature we plan to make when the SDK is out of beta (which is really soon).